# Html select with options as textboxes

Tags: html, select, textbox

I am writing an select drop down in html which has

```
<option><input type="text"></option>
```

But when I am running that program the textbox is coming out of the dropdown,the purpose of inserting text box in select is that , If a user is unable to find its desired option . He will be able to add a new one.

This is the select code. **You can see alive demo running this code http://jsfiddle.net/_nikhilagrawal/eJ7k6/3/**. Why this input type text is coming outside the select. Please have a look.

```
<select name="color"> 
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>    
    <option><input type="text" name="color" /></option>
</select>
```

This is the output of the drop down.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`<option>` elements cannot have anything other than text inside them.

If you want a widget that combines text inputs with a dropdown menu then you will have to build it using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can not write

```
<input type="text" name="color" />
```

inside `<option></option>` tag.

You should add textbox nearest to selectbox  If a user is unable to find its desired option,user can add new one. or you need to customize your select box using **css+jquery**

Comment: then is ok I cant use but what to do next